# Python Selenium, javascript button never finishing to load

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i'm doing a simple selenium script to get all products in this page: https://www.bauducco.com.br/produtos/.

I've just created this code to try to open the page and click in the red button to load more products:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time 

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'mypath')
driver.get('http://www.bauducco.com.br/produtos/')

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                 '/html/body/div[1]/div/section/div[2]/span/a')

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1080)") 


button.click()
time.sleep(5)
```

This is all the code. I've tried to execute using Google Chrome and also fireFox but none worked. The button just keep loading and never brings my content. Even if i just open the page with the selenium and click by myself the button doesn't work.

Some ideia what is happening ? Maybe is a trick to block bots ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add firefox webdriver option "--disable-web-security" because webdriver blocks CORS requests:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
firefox_options = Options()  
firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-web-security") 

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'mypath', 
firefox_options=firefox_options)
driver.get('http://www.bauducco.com.br/produtos/')

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/section/div[2]/span/a')

button.click()
```